# Regulate all buttons' looks at once in an android app, rather than individually?

Tags: android, button, attributes, controls

Is there a way to control how a group of buttons looks in an android app, rather than individually?

For example, if I have 8 buttons, and I want to change all of their minHeight to 50dp.  Or do I have to change the value for each one individually?  In a style.xml file or anywhere else.

Thanks!

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnWhite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#E0E0EB"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="54dp"
                android:minWidth="59dp"
                android:onClick="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="White"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGrey"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#E0E0EB"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="54dp"
                android:minWidth="59dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="Grey"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. What you can do is subclass the Button and use this customized version in your xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your res/values/styles.xml file find your AppTheme and declare a buttonStyle item:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/myButton</item>
</style>
```

Then declare your custom button style by extending android:style/Widget.Button:

```
<style name="myButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
  <item name="android:background">#f81</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#a39</item>
  <item name="android:text">"Click Me"</item>
</style>
```

which should change the style for all the buttons in your app.

Also as a note your application theme is deifined in your ApplicationManifest.xml and is

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

by default, which is why we make changes to the "AppTheme" style.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to implement a customized button by Java

(under package com.my.view)

```
class Button myButton extends Button {
    // Define your button here
}
```

In you .xml file,

```
<com.my.view.myButton>
    android:id="@+id/button_01"
</com.my.view.myButton>

<com.my.view.myButton>
    android:id="@+id/button_02"
</com.my.view.myButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your **style.xml** file, create a new style similar to the following:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle1" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">#e0e0eb</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">54dip</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">59dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <!-- add more attributes here -->
</style>
```

Then, within your activity's content layout XML file, apply your custom style to the button widget as shown below:

```
<Button
    style="@style/MyButtonStyle1"
    android:id="@android:id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
/>
```